# Referencing a list name with a variable

Tags: list, flutter, variables, dart

I'm new to programming so am probably missing something simple.

My aim is to call on a list from a result stored in a variable and pull a random entry from that List. The result 'categoryResult' is the correct List name but [random] is showing a single letter within the List name. When 'categoryResult' is replaced with hard code everything works as it should.

```
void getQuestion() async {
    categoryResult = category[catNo];

    final questions = await _firestore
        .collection('questions')
        .document(category[catNo])
        .collection(categoryResult[random])
        .document('question')
        .get();
    newQuestion = questions.data['$questionNumber'];
  }
```

Comment: Could you share with us the value of `categoryResult`? It would be way easier to trace the error if the variables had static types.

Comment: 'categoryResult' will always be the name of one of the lists and is printing as such to the console.   When calling on 'categoryResult', it looks to be treated as a String and so randomises the name rather than the contents of the list.

Comment: What's contained in your `random` variable? How is it defined and assigned?

Comment: int random = Random().nextInt(4);

Comment: So `categoryResult` is a String which means that when you e.g. are calling `categoryResult[0]` you are just getting the first letter of this String: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/String/operator_get.html

Comment: Am I missing a step?